# nginx try_files ignore folder name

Tags: nginx

I have a static website with only html files and some assets with the following structure:

```
|-- assets
|   |-- img
|   |   |-- logo.svg
|   |   |-- ...
|   |-- ...
|-- portfolio
|   |-- 2010
|   |   |-- a.html
|   |   |-- b.html
|   |   `-- c.html
|   |-- 2011
|   |   |-- d.html
|   |   |-- e.html
|   |   `-- f.html
|   |-- ...
|   |-- 2010.html
|   |-- 2011.html
|   `-- ...
|-- public
|   `-- portfolio
|       |-- a
|       |   |-- 43b1bd55-352e-49f1-b48e-e0560853c7f0.jpg
|       |   |-- 65f79481-7607-49bb-afbe-ba72fb64beb9.jpg
|       |   |-- 6fee92e0-65aa-4fb9-a593-3280750d9072.jpg
|       |   |-- 999907bc-3c60-440e-9fb8-4fd4de52e19f.jpg
|       |   `-- be98fbe9-20af-4246-b299-e9f6facc6624.jpg
|       |   ...
|-- _404.html
|-- index.html
|-- portfolio.html
|-- robots.txt
|-- sitemap.xml
`-- thank-you.html
```

for some reason, nginx refuses to find the `portfolio.html` and redirects to the folder even though the file `portfolio.html` exists.

site config file:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name project.com;

    autoindex off;

    root /var/www/project/front/_out;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    charset utf-8;

    index /index.html;

    error_page 404 /_404.html;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/$ /index.html break;
        try_files $uri $uri.html =404;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /sitemap.xml  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `redirects to the folder`? Can you show access and error logs and the response from `curl -I http://example.com/portfolio.html`

Comment: @RichardSmith portfolio.html works, but I want all the urls not to contain `.html`. that means that `http://example.com/portfolio` should display the `portfolio.html` not the `portfolio` folder.
`redirect to the folder` means it tries to display the contents of portfolio folder

Comment: Have you tried reversing the terms `$uri` and `$uri.html` in your `try_files` statement, so that it looks for the html file first?

Comment: @RichardSmith success! I did not think about it and wasted 2 hours :\ Thanks!